# Can i sum a multilookup values in reporting services 2008

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a case where I need to search for fix numbers (months ids from 1 to 12), in another dataset and return the sum of of return field.

I used `MultiLookUp` function it should be something like below:

```
=code.SumLookup(Multilookup(Split("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12" , ","),
Fields!Transaction_Month.Value,Fields!Total_O_S_Loss___LAE_Reserve.Value
, "DataSet3"))
```

Where `SumLookUp` is a code I used before for `LookUpSet` , but it seems that it doesn't work for `MultiLookUp`

```
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal() 
Public Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal 
    If items Is Nothing Then 
        Return Nothing
    End If 
    Dim ct as Integer = New Integer() 
    suma = 0 
    ct = 0 
    For Each item As Object In items 
        suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item) ct += 1 
    Next 
    If (ct = 0) Then 
        return 0 
    else return 
        suma  
End Function 

Public Function GetMyVal() as Decimal 
    GetMyVal = suma  
End Function
```

Can you provide some advise how to perform such thing..

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error? Which error?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the `sum` function?

```
=Sum(MultiLookup(...))
```

**Edit in a brain fart:**

What happens if one of the months don't return a value? I think the `multilookup` function will return a `nothing` for each `item` inside the `items` object (variantarray).

I would suggest you add in an `if` statement inside the for loop to catch any of these.